# Deleted languages & inputs are still available in the taskbar?

Tags: powershell, language

I created this script in the PowerShell to completely renew Windows 10 Languages and Inputs:

```
$LanguageList = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language en-us
$LanguageList.Add("sk")

ForEach ($language in $LanguageList)
{
    if ($language.LanguageTag -eq "sk")
    {
        $language.InputMethodTips.Clear()
        $language.InputMethodTips.Add("041B:0001041B")
    }
}

Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $LanguageList
```

I need this script because every day I´m receiving a new Virtual Machine from the Pool with pre-set languages and language inputs. Script is working fine (languages and inputs are renewed) but the input language methods are sometimes still available in taskbar.
I mean when I open the Settings in Windows 10 -> Time & Language -> Language I see the languages and inputs are renewed from the script (Renewed - some languages are deleted, new language "sk" is added with specific InputMethod). But when I open the language & inputs in the taskbar there are still old (deleted) language & inputs. I can switch between them with Alt + Shift. Existence of these old (deleted) languages & inputs in the taskbar makes this script completely useless. Some idea why the languages & inputs still exist in the taskbar?

I know one workaround for this problem: Restart a computer. But this is not acceptable workaround for me because when I restart my VM which was assigned to me from the Pool, I will lost my VM (another/new VM from the Pool will be assigned to me).

Comment: Once you remove the languages with the script, kill explorer.exe and then open a new instance and see if the deleted languages from the task bard disappear. You can run `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` and then `explorer.exe` in command prompt to start a new instance of explorer once the command have been run.

Comment: Good point but it didn´t work. After I restarted the explorer.exe process everything was okay until I lock the account and log in again. In the Windows 10 login screen deleted languages & inputs was back and after I logged in to the my account I saw deleted languages & inputs in taskbar again. When I check Windows 10 Settings - Languages there are only languages and inputs that I want but the Taskbar and the Lock screen is a another world...

Comment: Can you tell me if after the lock screen and unlock if you kill explorer.exe again and then restart it if that resolves the problem again temporarily? If so, I might be able to help you determine a simple way to automate the killing of explorer.exe and relaunching to refresh it's view with accurate content in the area of your concern assuming that the temp fix always fixes when it breaks again. It might be a bit brute force but if transparent, not too inconvenient and works to resolve a potential bug in Windows File Explorer you found, it might just suffice. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I tried it few times but the answer is no. Killing the process explorer.exe helped me the first time but never again. It´s riddiculous: https://imgur.com/a/VeCHTrM

Comment: I see, last but not least, I have two posts that seem related I wrote about in the past I want to share just in case. I wasn't sure if running `Set-WinSystemLocale en-US` and then running `Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US` in that order helps but here's the posts: https://superuser.com/questions/1309399/change-display-language-in-windows-10-with-cmd-or-powershell-commands/1310632#1310632 and even more on https://superuser.com/questions/1486956/remove-language-pack-in-windows-10/1487492#1487492. Hopefully these are what you need and remember the order may be important if I vaguely recall.

Comment: And one of those [just commented above] posts also have an answer by HarryMC that has some registry keys that can be purged to potentially help you resolve. Curious to hear if any of this helps or not.